# How to pass NSData as NSString and get it back?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, nsstring, nsdata

i have a NSData object.

**I want to convert it to a string, pass to a function and then reconvert back to NSData object.**

But How?

I tried this method, but NSData value it's different from the original!

here my code:

```
  // a generic class
  APClass *c = [[APClass alloc] init];
  c.aNumber = 123;
  c.aString = @"my string";

  // my data obj
  NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData data];

  // archiver to store class in nsdata
  NSKeyedArchiver *encoder = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
  [encoder encodeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:c.aNumber] forKey:@"aNum"];
  [encoder encodeObject:c.aString forKey:@"aStr"];
  [encoder finishEncoding];
  [encoder release];

  [c release];

  NSLog(@"%@", data);
  NSString *d = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", data];

  // ---

  NSString *strFromData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", d];

  NSData *dataNM = [strFromData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

  // decoder to retrieve class from nsdata      
  NSKeyedUnarchiver *decoder = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:dataNM];
  int number       = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"aNum"] intValue];
  NSString *string = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"aStr"];
  [decoder finishDecoding];
  [decoder release];

  NSLog(@"[Number: %d] -- [String: %@]", number, string);
```

How can i convert back to original NSData?

data and dataNM are different in size.
Compiler give back this error:

> 2012-04-02 16:33:28.269 DataTest[18008:f803] -[__NSCFData
>   objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b46c80
>
> 2012-04-02 16:33:28.270 DataTest[18008:f803] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[__NSCFData objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x6b46c80'

thanks.

Comment: In Creating NSData string value `data` is not set to anything, it is just an empty `NSMutableData`. In Getting NSData from NSString what is `d`, a NSString? More generally what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: `[encoder finishEncoding];` valorize data value that is initially empty. I need to pass an entire class between two applications using `NSKeyedArchiver`. Yes, `d` is the string created before.

Comment: Why convert to a `NSString`, why not just pass as `NSData`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Solved.

Using `dataUsingEncoding`, value of NSData it's different.

To pass data around methods or apps, etc, i've used base64 convertion.

## Encode

```
NSString *d = 
  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"appdue://obj=%@", 
     [APBase64Converter base64forData:data]];
```

## Decode

```
NSData *data = [APBase64Converter base64DataFromString:urlParams];
```

**APBase64Converter** Is a lib that encode/decode easily data and strings.

Working example and **APBase64Converter** lib can be downloaded from here: http://goo.gl/8YNjS

Thanks all.

I "retain" this post for helps people and me next time!

Comment: Is there any way to do this using Apple-provided functions instead of a third-party library?

Comment: i don't know. I use my lib in all projects. :)

Comment: Ok, followup question then. Has Apple accepted an app into the App Store containing this library, or is this just a personal/jailbreak project?

Comment: yes, it use simple funcions like this http://cocoadev.com/wiki/BaseSixtyFour. Nothing strange in code.

Answer (score 0):

Use
`NSData` to `NSString`:
`- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding`
and
`NSString` to `NSData`:
`- (NSData *)dataUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding`

with encoding
`NSUTF8StringEncoding`
or
`NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding` (which is an 8-bit encoding).

Comment: I need use `NSKeyedArchiver` to store NSData. `dataUsingEncoding`is already used. You think that is `initWithData` the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Use Base64 class it is available in github

```
        DatabaseResult* result = [self.database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM `images`       WHERE image_id = ? AND imagetype = ?", self.routeId,self.imagetype];

        for(EGODatabaseRow* row in result) {

        NSString *strImage=[row stringForColumn:@"image_photo"];

        [Base64 initialize];

        NSData *data = [Base64 decode:strImage];

        UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:data];

        }
```

This is how i convert String to data and then data to image.

Comment: What is DatabaseResult? EGODatabaseRow? Base64?

Comment: this is how i get base64 string from database. About Base64 i already mention it at the top of answer.